# Working SATA DVD drive doesn't work through a USB adaptor

Tags: windows-7, dvd

I have a SATA DVD drive designed for a desktop computer, not one of the thin laptop ones. It worked fine connected to the motherboard via SATA, but now I have it connected via a USB/SATA adaptor to my Windows 7 machine and it's not working. It shows up in My Computer, the LED flickers when I select "Eject" in the GUI, but it doesn't open. It doesn't even open when I press the physical eject button on the drive.

This drive previously worked (two months ago) via USB when connected via the same adaptor to a different, Windows XP machine.

What can I do to troubleshoot this?

Comment: It seems the new PC isn't giving enough power to that USB port. Or you have one of those adapters that don't work in USB3.0 ports.

Comment: @MichaelBay I tried the adaptor in USB2 and 3 ports. The USB adaptor I'm using gets power from the wall, by the way.

Comment: Are you using a USB hub?

Comment: @MichaelBay No.

Comment: Then I can only think of incompatibility.

Comment: Verify it works now; directly attach the drive VIA SATA to a motherboard and test it.  It probably works, but to be sure you have to test, otherwise you may be chasing a ghost.